# Rest-Api returns code 200 response , but doesn't insert the data

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I'm using the following method to insert some values in related table,in my local the api works fine and inserts the new data to the table.

**however in production I get 200 response, but nothing happens.**

both local and production are the same.

```
    [Route( "api/event/{eventType}/new" )]
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task AddEvent( string eventType, CancellationToken cancellationToken )
    {
      if ( string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace( eventType ) )
        throw new HttpResponseException( 400, "Route wrong: no valid eventType given" );

      using var reader      = new StreamReader( HttpContext.Request.Body, Encoding.UTF8 );
      var       postedEvent = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
      try {
        JsonConvert.DeserializeObject( postedEvent );
      } catch ( Exception ex ) {
        throw new HttpResponseException( 400, "Payload is not valid JSON" );
      }

      var testEvent= new TestEvent{ EventType = eventType, EventData = postedEvent };
      _dbContext.Events.Add( testEvent);
      await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync( cancellationToken );
    }
```

cURL:

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://productionSample.com/api/event/FirstCampaign/new' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer ...' \
--header 'Content-Type: text/plain' \
--data-raw '{ "id":"1", "campiagnName":"test"}'
```

Comment: first thoughts would be check configuration.  Are you definitely hitting your production URL?  Is your production app's `_dbContext` connection string definitely hitting the database you think it is?

Comment: It's kind of impossible to determine why data isn't being inserted in your production environment, there are just so many factors. Maybe something with your connection string to the DB?

Either way, having your controller invoke the DB directly is so horrible, it kind of scares me that this is running on a production environment. You really should have all DB reading/writing happening in a different project that has no knowledge of the API layer.

Comment: I just realized that _dbContext.Events.add should use async...
I will update this and then test on our production.

Comment: that's not going to change anything.  But good practice to do

Comment: @derpirscher EF exposes both `Add` and `AddAsync`.  If he is using `Add`, it's not returning a task and is not fire and forget.  If he were using `AddAsync` and not awaiting it, that would be an issue.